# How can I iterate through a python 2D list and delete/replace characters from a specific column?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following 2D list

```
data = [['2013-02-03', 'London', 'miles', '25'], ['2013-02-03', 'Newcastle', 'miles', '25'], ['2013-02-03', 'Birmingham', 'miles', '62']]
```

I need to be able to remove any of the `''` in a column 
e.g last column below so i can pass the 2D list to a javascript function in a text file.

```
data = [['2013-02-03', 'London', 'miles', 25], ['2013-02-03', 'Newcastle', 'miles', 25], ['2013-02-03', 'Birmingham', 'miles', 62]]
```

I have a function and can get the result on a single value

```
r = "['2013-02-03', 'London', 'miles', '25']"


def rreplace(s, old, new, occurrence):
    li = s.rsplit(old, occurrence)
    return new.join(li)

    rreplace(p, "'", '', 2)

"['2013-02-03', 'Feltham', 'less_than_one_day', 25],"
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve this result?

I have tried a number of ways using: for loops, map/lambda and 
iter, I can loop through the list or change an element in single list
just can't do both and output the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just process the list of values as Python:

```
for row in data:
    row[-1] = int(row[-1])
```

This replaces each last element in the `data` nested lists with their integer equivalent.

Next, use the `json` module to turn this into valid JavaScript:

```
import json

r = json.dumps(data)
```

JSON is a subset of JavaScript after all.

Quick demo:

```
>>> data = [['2013-02-03', 'London', 'miles', '25'], ['2013-02-03', 'Newcastle', 'miles', '25'], ['2013-02-03', 'Birmingham', 'miles', '62']]
>>> for row in data:
...     row[-1] = int(row[-1])
... 
>>> data
[['2013-02-03', 'London', 'miles', 25], ['2013-02-03', 'Newcastle', 'miles', 25], ['2013-02-03', 'Birmingham', 'miles', 62]]
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(data)
'[["2013-02-03", "London", "miles", 25], ["2013-02-03", "Newcastle", "miles", 25], ["2013-02-03", "Birmingham", "miles", 62]]'
```

Comment: Do you know if there any way to write it in a more pythonic way, using list comprehension or map ?

Comment: @ibi0tux: You can, but there isn't really much point in recreating the rest of the lists, is there? Using the loop is more efficient in this specific case. `data = [elem[:-1] + [int(elem[-1])] for elem in data]` is not nearly as readable either.

Comment: @ibi0tux: Using newer syntax doesn't always make for more pythonic code.

Comment: I was just wondering this because i tried and get stuck on writing it with an alternative syntax.

Comment: I had to add for row in data [1:]:
    row[-1] = int(row[-1])

Comment: To skip the top title row, which I didn't include in my question.